# php and curl - waiting for what?

Tags: php, apache, curl

A quicky - three .php pages with some form data passed from page0->page1->page2. When 'submit' gets clicked on page0 it goes to page1, etc. No big deal.

Im trying to use curl to do the page transfer after the form data is stored. This shouldn't be a big deal.. right?

Each page is short, simple HTML. Nothing special. They should load in a heartbeat. And they do from my local apache server. When I put them on our dept server (also running apache) the first page loads and then.. nothing.. I can load them all separately but I can't seem to link between them. After a few minutes the page times out. No error messages.

I checked the .php build on the server and curl is definitely installed.

What am I missing? Its got to be something obvious.

```
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://server.org/php/forms/form1.php?lid=" . $lastId );
curl_exec( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if cURL has trouble executing using other URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: check that the server you're accessing is actually accessible from where the script is run and that DNS works properly.

Then again, I don't really understand what's the purpose of this. Why not just use include? Or are all the pages on different servers?

> All pages are on the same server. I want to have them appear sequentially when the form on each is submitted. IE fill out form0, submit it, then go on to page 1, etc

Then you don't need any roundtrips with curl or anything else.

Either use

```
include 'form1.php'; // you will have the $lastId variable there
```

or

```
header('Location: form1.php?lid='.$lastId);
```

Comment: All pages are on the same server. I want to have them appear sequentially when the form on each is submitted. IE fill out form0, submit it, then go on to page 1, etc

Comment: @ethrbunny Than you don't need to use CURL.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see what the $ch is on the first page.

Maybe you're closing an invalid handle.

Also, if you're looking to return the page data I believe you've missed some of the options.

Comment: Not sure about 'page data' - just want to have each page appear when I submit the previous form.